# split cell into array in excel for specify length

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, split

I have some question that I can not handle. I have multiple cells with the long text strings (20 to 60 characters). I want to change each cell into array with the partial text, lets say 5 character length. 
I know that there is some function that enable to split/change into array by space or specific character, but here I need to split the text in smaller  portion, to use it to some search scripts.

Comment: Have you tried using `Mid`? Please include what you have already tried.

Comment: there is no inbuilt feature for such feat.

Comment: @  arcadeprecinct I tried some vba to divide the text for characters, but could not find how to spit the text for specify length text, and how to create the the array. mid is not a proper function  'cuz can not count the length of the source text.

Comment: @Adam if you can't count the length of the source text, you need to explain further because when dealing with strings you know the length.

Comment: @arcadeprecinct it's not that I don't know the length, but the mid function did not works for input entities withe the different length. Firs have to check the source data length to split to all possible array entries from 1st to the last that will be 5 character length.

Comment: @Adam that's what loops are for. Check the length, divide by 5 to find out how long your array will be, redim the array, fill array with loop like in Jaques' answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have a cell which contains something like this:

```
A1: AAAAABBBBBCCCCCDDDDD
```

Using the MID() function might help you.  For example:

```
B1: =MID(A$1,1,5)
C1: =MID(A$1,1*5+1,5)
D1: =MID(A$1,2*5+1,5)
..: =MID(A$1,...*5+1,5)
```

Comment: I have the table with the 120k row and 22 columns, the source text cells are different length, so I have to check its length at first and then divid it into 5 characters length array entries. It also would be great to define the target array entries length.

Answer (score -1):

I have the table with the 120k row and 22 columns, the source text cells are different length, so I have to check its length at first and then divid it into 5 characters length array entries. It also would be great to define the target array entries length.

Comment: Please edit your question rather than posting it as an answer.

Comment: @arcadeprecinct my apology, wring button.